# Emacs auto-complete-c-headers won't work with quotation marks

Tags: c++, c, emacs, emacs24

I am using:

- Linux Manjaro
- GNU Emacs 24.3.1, the updated standard Emacs package in Manjaro.
- The Emacs packages [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) and [auto-complete-c-headers](https://github.com/mooz/auto-complete-c-headers) from Melpa.

The relevant parts of my .emacs file are the following (there is very little else in my .emacs file right now, I have tried to reduce it to a minimum when investigating this issue).

```
;; Auto-complete
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
      (lambda()
        (ac-config-default)))

;; Auto-complete C/C++ header file names
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (lambda()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/4.9.1")
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/backward")
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include")
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed")))
```

Auto-completion works perfectly for:

```
#include <iost...
```

But not for:

```
#include "MyCla...
```

It does however work for:

```
#include <MyCla...
```

although MyClass.hpp is not a system include file (and is located under ./, which is a standard search path for auto-complete-c-headers). But then I have to edit the bracket and change it to a quotation mark.

Looking at the code for auto-complete-c-headers, it looks to me that the quotation mark case should work.

Any idea about what could be causing this issue?

I am thinking that maybe Emacs enters in some kind of mode after the

```
#include "
```

that prevents it from taking suggestions from auto-complete-c-headers.

I am mostly very pleased with my latest Emacs experiences as a programmer's editor, and I would be thankful for any hint on how to solve this little irritation.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, as an imperfect solution, you can use:

```
(setq ac-disable-faces nil)
```

This will enable auto compelete between quotation marks.
If that won't work, try to combine it with *autopair* or *electric-pair-mode*.